# How do I create a time series in R from Bureau of Economic Analysis Data?

Tags: r, time-series

[BEA Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlEhc.png)

I have a data frame (image above) with data from all 50 states plus DC that lists state economic output (in millions of current dollars) for three combined industry segments from 1997-2015.

How do I create a time series from data in this particular format?

Comment: 1. don't post a picture of data. can you do this? dput(head(dataframe,10)), then copy and paste that here. We will all be able to manipulate your data. 2. what is a time series? show what you want your output to be.

Comment: SO is not a "build my project for me" site. Do searching to show that you have made an effort to learn R time series concepts. (There is an entire CRAN Task View on time series.) Put in code and data (as text) that shows you have made some effort. Maybe start by doing a search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D++economic+data+download

Comment: @leeum I tried to do that but it was too much code relative to the amount of text that I had. Thankfully, the answer below was what I needed. I wasn't sure if a multivariate time series could be in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have `Lines` as shown below.  Then we can read it into a data frame specifying that the row names are in column 1.   If it is in a file instead replace `text = Lines` with something like `"myfile"`.  In R, multivariate time series are normally in columns, not rows, so we transpose it and create a zoo series from that.

At this point it can be used as is or converted using `as.ts(z)`, `fortify.zoo(z)`, `fortify.zoo(z, melt = TRUE)`, `coredata(z)` or `time(z)` among other possibilities.

```
Lines <- "
Area 1997 1998 1999
A       1    2    3
B       4    5    6"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE, row.names = 1)

library(zoo)
z <- zoo(t(DF), as.numeric(colnames(DF)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that I had to reformat my data because every time series that I saw was a column instead of a row, but I wanted to make sure that there wasn't an alternate approach.